# Windows: How to double-click on word and only highlight that word?

Tags: windows, highlighting

In any textbox or editor of any sort on any version of **Windows**, if you **double-click** on a word, it highlights both the word and any space or tab characters that follow it.

What is the use of this feature? How can I change it so that only the word is highlighted?

Comment: It's not all editors. In Visual Studio and Notepad++ only the current word is highlighted. I'm guessing that in most word processors when you past a word your usually going to type something else in a sentence and a space is usually required.

Comment: in VIM also only the word is highlighted, and there you can also count with the shortcut "viw" to "visualize-in-word"

Answer (score -3):

Use of the feature is "to select the text below the cursor" And I think, when you double click on any word in any textbox or any page, the word gets selected. It doesn't include the space or tab. May be you are speaking of any editor. Please let us know the exact details. Thanks.

Comment: Mohan: Try it in Notepad or a Gmail compose textbox. Type a sentence, double-click on any letter of a word, the word and its following space/tab characters are highlighted.

Comment: Okay. I tested this on both Windows and Mac. Mac doesn't behave like this. In Mac, Gmail, compose, its selecting only the word.

Comment: Mohan: That is precisely why I called this a Windows question :-)

Comment: and thats why it gets a downvote from me.